# (node:1122) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, unhandled

Im creating an algorithm using Node.js. I have all of my data linked up to a firebase database and am trying to revive. The problem is i need a lot of requests and after i try to execute around 5-8 requests i receive the error-

> (node:1167) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'weather' of undefined

I am unsure weather there is a limit of requests i can make or if i am not understanding what a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning really is.

Please help

Comment: Could you show some code,.  You say a lot of requests.. If you make lots of promises without doing some sort of throttling most back ends are going to barf.

Comment: thanks for your comment - i added the code in this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692982/unable-to-query-json-with-js)@Keith